# shiny cannot find object when plotting ggmap

Tags: r, object, ggplot2, error-handling, shiny

I want to be able to subset a data frame based on user input and colour regions of a map.

I can set up RShiny to read in the data frame and make a histogram of a region and indicator successfully, but when I try to include the code for the map, I receive an error saying `"Error: object 'x5' not found".` x5 is the subset of data from which I read in.

My code is as follows:

```
library(shiny)
library(xlsx)
library(rgdal)
library(rgeos)
library(sp)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggmap)
require(RgoogleMaps)

x3=readRDS('LSOAData.RDS') #data frame, 150k x 110

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel('LSOA Maps of London'),
  column(3,
         selectInput('borough','Borough',
                     choices = unique(x3$LA_NAME)),
         selectInput('measure','Metric to View',
                     choices = colnames(x3[c(10:17)]))
  ),
  column(3,plotOutput('hist')),
  column(6,plotOutput('LSOAMap'))
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output){

  output$hist <- renderPlot({
    hist(x3[x3$LA_NAME==input$borough,input$measure],main=input$borough,ylab='Freq',xlab=input$measure)
  })

  output$LSOAMap <- renderPlot({
    x4=x3[x3$LA_NAME==input$borough,]

    pp=x4[,c('long','lat')]
    RegionOfInterest <- get_map(location = c(lon = mean(pp$long), lat = mean(pp$lat)),
                                zoom = 12,
                                maptype = "roadmap", scale = 2)
    x5=droplevels(x4)
    colnum=which(colnames(x3)=='IMD Score')
    #plot(colnum)
    x5$Measure=cut(x5[,colnum],3)
#    barplot(table(x5$Measure))
    #colour code each LSOA
    RegionOfInterestMap=ggmap(RegionOfInterest) +
      geom_polygon(aes(x=x5$long, y=x5$lat, group=group,fill=x5$Measure),
                   size=.5,color='black', data=x5, alpha=.5) +
      scale_fill_manual(values=c('green','yellow','red3'),
                        labels=c('Low','Medium','High'),
                        name='Value')+
      ggtitle(paste0(input$measure,' in ',input$borough,' by LSOA'))+
      theme(axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
            axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
            axis.text.y = element_blank(),
            axis.text.x = element_blank())
    RegionOfInterestMap
  })    

})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The commented out line `#    barplot(table(x5$Measure))` (line 45)I used to ensure that everything upto that point worked fine (with the remaining commented out, lines 46-58, ie no ggmap plotted), and it does, as does the barplot of the values from x5. Thus, it can read from object x5!

[image]

BUT, when I try with the line in and try to print the map, I get:

[image]

I am trying for in place of the error

[image]

Any suggestions welcomed.

The barplot can read from x5, but ggplot cannot!

Comment: Is there a reason you reference both `x5$long` (et al) *and* `data=x5` in your plot commands? Seems redundant to me. @wxxyyyzz seems to believe that that is the source of your problem, but since your question is not reproducible it is impossible to know for certain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For ggplot, you don't have to put x5$ there.
Try aes(x=long, y=lat, ..., data=x5, ...

Comment: Does this really solve the problem? When I do `ggplot(mtcars, aes(disp,mpg)) + geom_point(aes(x=mtcars$disp,y=mtcars$cyl), data=mtcars)` (suffering from the same problematic method), it still works as expected.

Comment: that worked, thanks! removed x5$ stuff, and kept the reference to x5 out of the aes to get it to work: geom_polygon(aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group,fill=Measure),
                   size=.5,color='black', alpha=.5,data=x5) +

Comment: Weird, I had the same idea, but I checked that `ggplot() + geom_point(aes(x=iris$Petal.Width, y=iris$Petal.Length), data=iris)` works.

Comment: @r2evans  you also need to remove those in your geom_point() statement. It will treat your x as a variable. disp is, but mtcars$disp is not. Hope this answers your question

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Interesting. Do you have iris dataset in your environment?

Comment: @wxxyyyzz, I know they "should" be removed, but *"don't have to put"* to me is different than *"things will actually break unless you remove"*. My question was based on a couple things: (a) the OP is not reproducible, so how do you know that your suggestion would fix the error? In hindsight, since it was accepted, that suggests "yes", though I honestly don't see how (since the code in my comment worked); and (b) if you are certain that that problem would generate `'x5' not found` error, then an answer should have some measure of reproducibility on its own, while this answer seems rather terse.

Comment: @r2evans You are right. I did not reproduce the same error. I am new here. Please bear with it.  It was just my first thought and I might just got lucky. I guess I should have put it as a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: Sure, I understand. I'm not attacking so much as trying to ensure some level of quality in answers. If the answer does not work (error), does not fix the problem, is not reproducible, or should be a comment, I'll often leave a note. One thing to consider is making it so that somebody coming to the question with a seemingly-similar problem can find something actionable if not executable in the accepted answer.